# Java swing.How to override component methods in intellij idea GUI desinger

Tags: java, swing

Well,now I'm working on a swing project in intellij idea.And when I drag a Jtable named table1 in the GUI design form to a Jframe,a statement will generate automatically,such as:

```
public class TableTest extends JFrame{
private JTable table1;   
}
```

And in the future code,table1 could be used directly without new a instance just like`JTable table1 = new JTable()`.But generally,override appears when a instance is created just like

```
JTable table1 = new JTable(){
    @override
    .....
}
```

So is confused me that can I override methods without new a interface?How can I do that?

Comment: why would you need the @Override annotation? My advice: don't use some code generator, especially not if it doesn't generate the code you want

Comment: Ohh...It seems that the question I just edited was incomplete and I've just reedited it. In fact , I want to override some Jtable methods so that achieve my target

Comment: For anyone else reading this question, skip the GUI builder and build your GUI by hand so you understand how the Swing components fit together.  This Oracle tutorial will help you understand.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice.@GilbertLeBlanc To be honest I'm a beginner in JAVA ,so I'll try to build a GUI by hand. But I still want to know is the question above feasible？

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc unfortunately, the last few versions of Java, the second step of that tutorial is "hey, here's how the NetBeans WYSIWYG works"